# IBM Worklight 6.1.0.1 Console Error "Invalid authority field: [http:"

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I'm trying to upload a super simple "Hello World" Worklight application (with the iPhone and Android environments) to a remote server (Worklight + DB2) using the WL Console. Every time I push the .wlapp, I get the following error:

*"Failed to deploy application 'HelloWorld-all.wlapp'. Invalid authority field: [http:"*

---

I've attempted to upload the .wlapp with and without the following configuration:

**worklight.properties:**

```
#publicWorkLightHostname=localhost
publicWorkLightHostname=50.23.127.211
# HTTP or HTTPS
publicWorkLightProtocol=HTTP
# For default port leave empty
publicWorkLightPort=9080

...

# For DB2
wl.db.url=jdbc:db2:WRKLGHT
# For Oracle

wl.db.username={the system username with DB2 access}
wl.db.password={the system password}
```

---

Regarding a sample, as I mentioned before it's just the boilerplate code that comes with a new Worklight 6.1.0.1 project when you go to File -> New Worklight Project -> Hybrid Application -> Finish, add two environments (iPhone and Android), and choose Run -> Build All when you right click the app. I've tried with and without the server config above (Paul Yuan mentioned that he didn't think anything else was required to deploy since there's no authentication [adapter, form, etc.]).

Comment: Can you also provide the settings you included for your remote server. I have a feeling you may not be pointing to a valid address and that is why this error occurs

Comment: 1) Carlos Paez, Paul Yuan, Michael R. Rheinheimer, Eliran Ben Ishay (Mobile CoC and Worklight team...forgive my generalization).
2) Nothing regarding the error in either messages.log or the FFDC log files.
3) Red Hat Enterprise with Worklight + DB2 (Softlayer instance managed by DST, setup by myself manually using the steps @ the following URL:http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r0m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.worklight.help.doc%2Fadmin%2Ft_setting_up_your_db2_database_manually.html 
4) Creating a new WL project, adding the two environments and selecting "Build All" under Run.

Comment: What happens when you take Softlayer out of the equation? That is, try to deploy to a regular Worklight Development Server in Eclipse? Just to pin-point to area this is happening. Could be a network issue.

Comment: @user3634050, would be nice to have a reply from you after a whole year of waiting for it.

Answer (score 0):

The current assumption is that this error occurs due to a mis-configruation in Software layer, as worklight is simply a web app deployed onto it and does not control the network setup.

Here is a similar error:

- http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21408732